# Search function for a trie tree

Tags: c++, search, trie

I have made a search function that seems to work for passing the tester. I am just unsure if it will always be without errors. Can someone tell me if they see any flaws in the logic, and if so, where to look to improve?

**Search function**

```
//looks up the word in the  object. If it is in the object,true is returned. 
//You can assume that the word will be all lower case.
bool search(const string& word) const {

    if (!root_) {
            return false;
    }

    Node* curr = root_;

    for (int i = 0; i < word.length(); i++)
    {
            int idx = curr->getIndex(word[i]);

            if (idx < 0 || idx >= 26){
                    return false;
            }
            if (!curr->children_[idx]) {
                    return false;
            }
            curr = curr->children_[idx];

    }
    return curr->isTerminal_ == true;
}
```

**Trie node**

```
struct Node {
            bool isTerminal_;
            char ch_;
            Node* children_[26];
            Node(char c = '\0') {
                    isTerminal_ = false;
                    ch_ = c;
                    for (int i = 0; i < 26; i++) {
                            children_[i] = nullptr;
                    }
            }
            //given lower case alphabetic charachters ch, returns 
            //the associated index 'a' --> 0, 'b' --> 1...'z' --> 25
            int getIndex(char ch) {
                    return ch - 'a';
            }
    };
    Node* root_;
```

Comment: What's the "tester"?

Answer (score 1):

### Design.

Looks like perfectly good `C` but its not `C++`.

You should create a `Tree` class that wraps the node and acts as the interface to all your operations and handles all the resource management. None of these essential parts are currently done.

I would expect an interface like:

```
class Tree
{
    public:
        void addWord(std::string const& word);
        bool isWork(std::string const& word);
};
```

The code that you provided looks like it would work but this is far from a complete object and thus not really worth reviewing further.